# how to solve without loop or recursions, puzzling?

Tags: python, list

i want to make a function that takes a list as an input and return values when there are two of the same elements.The list is sorted.I can't use any loops or recursions is there any way it is possible?

```
def continuity(lst):
    if len(lst)==1:
        return 'no'
    elif lst[0]==lst[1]:
        return 'yes'
    else:
        return continuity(lst[1:])
```

this is what i did but it uses recursion.

Comment: what are the values? number or string?

Comment: values are numbers

Comment: Use the fact that a set only contains unique values.

Comment: Why did you name your function `continuity`? I think you have misunderstood the question if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Create a set for the same & then compare the length:

```
def continuity(lst):
    lst_set = set(lst)
    return 'yes' if len(lst_set) == len(lst) and len(lst) != 1 else 'no'
```

Using `counter`:

```
def continuity(lst):
    from collections import Counter
    occurrences = list(Counter(x).values())
    sum = sum(occurrences)
    return 'yes' if sum == len(lst_set) and len(lst) != 1 else 'no'
```

Comment: is there a way even besides set

Answer (score 0):

```
def continuity(lst):
    if len(lst) > 1
        if len(lst) == len(set(lst)):
            return 'yes'
        else:
            return 'no'
    else:
        return 'no'
```

Comment: will fail if the len of lst is 1